# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') at HTMLAnchorElement.animateit animateit @

Tags: javascript

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at HTMLAnchorElement.animateit 
animateit @
```

This is my code:

```
(function () {

      const aLink = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

      const animateit = function (e) {
            const span = this.querySelector('span');
            const { offsetX: x, offsetY: y } = e,
            { offsetWidth: width, offsetHeight: height } = this,

            move = 35,
            xMove = x / width * (move * 2) - move,
            yMove = y / height * (move * 2) - move;

            span.style.transform = `translate(${xMove}px, ${yMove}px)`;

            if (e.type === 'mouseleave') span.style.transform = '';
      };

      aLink.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('mousemove', animateit));
      aLink.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('mouseleave', animateit));

})();
```

HTML Code:

```
<li>
    <a href="#home" class="dot active" data-scroll="home">
      <svg  version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 547.596 547.596" xml:space="preserve" fill="currentColor"><g><path d="M540.76,254.788L294.506,38.216c-11.475-10.098-30.064-10.098-41.386,0L6.943,254.788c-11.475,10.098-8.415,18.284,6.885,18.284h75.964v221.773c0,12.087,9.945,22.108,22.108,22.108h92.947V371.067c0-12.087,9.945-22.108,22.109-22.108h93.865c12.239,0,22.108,9.792,22.108,22.108v145.886h92.947c12.24,0,22.108-9.945,22.108-22.108v-221.85h75.965C549.021,272.995,552.081,264.886,540.76,254.788z"/></g></svg>
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#about" class="dot" data-scroll="about">
      <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"width="32.000000pt" height="32.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 32.000000 32.000000"preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g transform="translate(0.000000,32.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"fill="currentColor" stroke="none"><path d="M17 304 c-13 -13 -8 -269 5 -282 18 -18 262 -17 277 2 8 9 11 57 9 147 l-3 134 -141 3 c-77 1 -143 -1 -147 -4z m123 -38 c0 -2 3 -11 6 -19 9 -23 -24 -49 -47 -37 -19 10 -26 40 -12 53 7 8 53 10 53 3z m140 -36 c0 -5 -18 -10 -40 -10 -22 0 -40 5 -40 10 0 6 18 10 40 10 22 0 40 -4 40 -10z m0 -50 c0 -5 -18 -10 -40 -10 -22 0 -40 5 -40 10 0 6 18 10 40 10 22 0 40 -4 40 -10z m-116 -22 c22 -31 12 -38 -55 -38 -44 0 -59 4 -59 14 0 45 86 64 114 24z m-74 -88 c0 -5 -7 -10 -15 -10 -8 0 -15 5 -15 10 0 6 7 10 15 10 8 0 15 -4 15 -10z m60 0 c0 -5 -7 -10 -15 -10 -8 0 -15 5 -15 10 0 6 7 10 15 10 8 0 15 -4 15 -10z m50 0 c0 -5 -7 -10 -15 -10 -8 0 -15 5 -15 10 0 6 7 10 15 10 8 0 15 -4 15 -10z m60 0 c0 -5 -7 -10 -15 -10 -8 0 -15 5 -15 10 0 6 7 10 15 10 8 0 15 -4 15 -10z"/></g></svg>
        <span>About</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I was expectiong to just work normally... But it work sbut I dont now what has happened but it shows that style is null.

Comment: Show your html as well

Comment: Based on the message it seems that `const span = this.querySelector('span');` resulted in `null`. Presumably there is at least one anchor element without a `<span>` inside.

Comment: Ok on second ...

Comment: Thank You @tevemadar IT WORKED i had one element not having that span